# Wrap section title around figure

Tags: sectioning, wrapfigure

I have a twosided document and want to add some wrapfigures. The specialty is that I want wrapped section titles on left pages.

The example shows the problem for the second section. For the first and third everything is fine.

MWE:

```
    \documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{scrbook}

    \usepackage{wrapfig}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{caption}
    \usepackage[english]{babel}
    \usepackage{blindtext}

    \begin{document}
        \chapter{First Chapter}
        \section{First Section}
        \begin{wrapfigure}[14]{o}{0.4\linewidth}
            \begin{center}
                \includegraphics[width=0.75\linewidth]{picture}
            \end{center}
            \vspace*{-1em}
            \captionsetup{width=0.75\linewidth}
            \caption[short]{long.}
        \end{wrapfigure}

        \blindtext[5]


        \section{Second Section}
        \begin{wrapfigure}[14]{o}{0.4\linewidth}
            \begin{center}
                \includegraphics[width=0.75\linewidth]{picture}
            \end{center}
            \vspace*{-1em}
            \captionsetup{width=0.75\linewidth}
            \caption[short]{long.}
        \end{wrapfigure}

        \blindtext

        \section{Third Section}
        \begin{wrapfigure}[14]{o}{0.4\linewidth}
            \begin{center}
                \includegraphics[width=0.75\linewidth]{picture}
            \end{center}
            \vspace*{-1em}
            \captionsetup{width=0.75\linewidth}
            \caption[short]{long.}
        \end{wrapfigure}

        \blindtext

    \end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: actually the third section title is on wrong place. this is caused because the text in this section is to short for correct warping for image (it has 13 lines, but you reserved for wrapping 14 lines; this confuse wraping). if you would extend this text, for example with `\blindtext[2]`, then all section titles will appear on the left side of the text as they should be.

Comment: Yes, this is true and intended. I like it better when the title is above the text and not above the image.

Another possible solution would be to make two columns, one for the images and one for the text. Is it possible to place images on the inner column?

Comment: this is with `wrapfigure` impossible to achieve. you should find another way (if exist).

Answer (score 3):

what you like to obtain is not possible to do only with `wrapfigure`. as solution can be enclosed sections' titles into `\parbox`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{scrbook}

\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{refcount}
\newcounter{secalign}
\newcommand{\secmove}{
    \refstepcounter{secalign}
    \label{secmove-\thesecalign}
    \mbox{}\par\noindent%
    \ifodd\getpagerefnumber{secmove-\thesecalign}
        \parbox{#1}{#2}
    \else
        \hfill\parbox{#1}{#2}
    \fi}

\begin{document}
    \chapter{First Chapter}
    \secmove{0.58\linewidth}{\section{First Section}}
    \begin{wrapfigure}[11]{o}{0.4\linewidth}
        \centering
            \includegraphics[width=0.75\linewidth]{picture}
        \captionsetup{skip=0.5ex, width=0.75\linewidth}
        \caption[short]{long.}
    \end{wrapfigure}
    \blindtext[5]

    \secmove{0.58\linewidth}{\section{Second Section}}
    \begin{wrapfigure}[11]{o}{0.4\linewidth}
        \centering
            \includegraphics[width=0.75\linewidth]{picture}
         \captionsetup{skip=0.5ex, width=0.75\linewidth}
        \caption[short]{long.}
    \end{wrapfigure}
    \blindtext

    \secmove{0.58\linewidth}{\section{Third Section}}
    \begin{wrapfigure}[11]{o}{0.4\linewidth}
        \centering
            \includegraphics[width=0.75\linewidth]{picture}
        \captionsetup{skip=0.5ex, width=0.75\linewidth}
        \caption[short]{long.}
    \end{wrapfigure}
    \blindtext[2]
\end{document}
```

solution in above code is aware, on which page (odd or even) the sections' titles are, however it need to be compiled at least twice.

note: what you claim that section position is work correct actually happens by accident as consequence of wrong `wrapfigure` settings (you declare to it use more line numbers as text beside of figure has),

beside this i made the following (off-topic) changes to your code:

- to `\captionsetup` ad option `skip=0.5ex` and the remove all `\vspace*{-1em}` in `wrapfigure`
- replace `\begin{centering}` with `\centering` and with this remove additional vertical space abobe and below image
- erase `\end{centering}`
- remove empty line between `wrapfigure` and `\blindtext` (or real text). this is important since with enclosing `sections` in `parbox` it lost capability to remove `parindent` in the following text.

Comment: I use sometimes `\wrapfigure`. This answer is very important for me. +1 (upvote).

Comment: @Sebastiano, thank you very much! `wrapfigure` is very capricious environment :-)  what op claim that work correctly actually happens by accident ... as consequence of wrong `wrapfigure` settings ....

Comment: With such sincerity I realized that wrapfigure is very capricious environment. In this period I am writing a physics book together with a university professor in memory of my beloved dad. At the end of the work, which is still almost half-finished, I will try to at least improve the appearance of the text, which I hope will be published, appropriately placing the images. You will always have my upvotes :-)